# Runescape 3 Black screen

Tags: runescape

I have played Runescape 3 many times before, but it seems that after this divination update, all I manage to get is a black screen with the interface. I can't actually see the live game, but I can see the live minimap.

Anyone else having this problem? And does anyone know how to fix it. I changed my graphics to the lowest settings, and nothing seemed to change.

Comment: What operating system do you use by the way?

Comment: I am using Windows 7, but I have also been having the issue on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The black screen is a bug that was very common before RuneScape 3 (22 July 2013). However, after RS3 was released, the chance of receiving a black screen was very low. And if you did get one, it would go away after a few seconds.

However, after the Divination update, I, and some other players, have noticed that black screens are now more common when you log in.

There is a fantastic technical page on the RuneScape website which deals with black screens. You can read it [here](http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/The_Game_Won%27t_Load#I_click_.E2.80.98Play_now.E2.80.99_and_the_screen_goes_black).

---

As you have told me you use Windows 7, try the following steps when you encounter a black screen:

1. Update/ reinstall Graphics Drivers
2. Clear Jagex cache
3. Reinstall Java
4. Reduce display settings

There's more detail on the link provided above.

Comment: You do a good job of explaining the problem, but all of the information to solve it is behind the link; can you add the steps needed to solve the issue?

Comment: @fbueckert Depends on the OP's operating system: which I'll ask about.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a problem that people have been experiencing for the last 2 days. What people have found to work is to log into a non-members world first then into a members world. After the black screen should go away after about 2 minutes. To fix the time wait change your settings to low graphics then wait for it to load. After change it to your original level.

This bug has been experienced by other players and they have all fixed the problems this way.

Comment: Where did you learn this?  Please include your source.

Comment: @fbueckert There is no source listed except from personal experiences and other players.

Comment: So you talked to others playing the game?  That's some useful context to add to your answer.

Comment: Hopping from a non mems world to a members world is never fun. All your member stats get reduced to 5.

Comment: @Haidro Your stats return to normal when you go back to a members world.

Comment: @YoungGuilo Is this a recent update :o?

Comment: @Haidro It has always been that way. I go F2P to sell off rune gear. Then I just go back.

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally still get these. A solution I have found for if you run a dual monitor set-up:

1. Disconnect your second monitor
2. Start RS3
3. Reconnect the monitor

Comment: That seems like a problem caused by the dual monitor setup, and not specific to Runescape.

Comment: I think you're right, it appears to be either Windows, or NVIDIA causing the problem, but still may solve it for people encountering the issue. 

In case interested, the issue exists in other programs too: https://www.reddit.com/r/NativeInstruments/comments/punmno/native_access/